# How can I duplicate a row and append it directly after the duplicated row using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I've been trying to figure this problem for a couple of hours now and seem to reach a dead end everytime. A small example of what I want to do is shown below.

| Normal Series |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |

| Duplicated Series |
| --- |
| a |
| a |
| b |
| b |
| c |
| c |
| d |
| d |

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with `loc` and `df.index.repeat`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)]
  Normal Series
0             a
0             a
1             b
1             b
2             c
2             c
3             d
3             d
>>>
```

Or with `reset_index`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)].reset_index(drop=True)
  Normal Series
0             a
1             a
2             b
3             b
4             c
5             c
6             d
7             d
>>>
```

Comment: This answer makes sense, but it's giving me an error indicating that indices are out of bounds `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds`

Comment: @MohammadGhassan Edited my answer with working code, feel free to mark this if it helps

Answer (score -1):

You can just concat a duplicated series together and sort it.

```
sample = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'])
output = pd.concat([sample,sample]).sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
output
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case as not all values are unique.

Comment: @MohammadGhassan The question asked didn't specify the constrain. But with constrain, the sample code will be:

`sample = pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b','c','d'])  
output = pd.concat([sample,pd.Series(sample.unique())]).sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)`